# Using boost::multiprecision as data type for blitz++

Tags: boost, blitz++

I am trying to do arbitrary precision arithmetic combined with the nice array syntax from blitz++. My problem is, that the generic math functions like `cos`, `exp` and so on don't work:

```
#include <blitz/array.h>
#include <boost/multiprecision/float128.hpp>

using namespace boost::multiprecision;
using namespace blitz;

int main() {

    float128 a = 1;
    a = cos(a);
    cout << a << endl;

    Array<float128,3> myarray(2,3,4);
    myarray = 1;
    myarray = cos(myarray);
    cout << myarray;

}
```

`g++ test.cpp -lquadmath -o test`

The first block, using only float128 but not blitz, works fine. The second block with blitz however won't do the `cos(myarray)`. The compiler seemingly figures out the iteration, but can not find the function to do the actual `cos(x)` for the values: [Compiler error log](http://pastebin.com/Bi0qimFf)

I would also like to use `boost::multiprecision::mpfr`, but one thing at a time. I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution, but it involves patching blitz. I have written [this](http://pastebin.com/eG4Bpwxb) patch for blitz-0.10 and with the modified blitz the above code just works.